# yaml2xml/xml2yaml implementation available?

Tags: xml, yaml

What yaml2xml and xml2yaml tools are available?

I googled [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=21461), but it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried yaml2xml.py?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=21461

There's a problem with the script mentioned in that page, if you try this version it should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from yaml import load
from gnosis.xml.pickle import dumps
from sys import stdin
print dumps(load(stdin.read()))
```

Make sure the appropriate modules are installed, then make it executable and run it:

```
chmod +x ./yaml2xml.py
cat ./inputfile.yaml | ./yaml2xml.py
```